# Form textfield on-click remove default values

Tags: 7, forms

My objective is to automatically remove the default values within the form textfields upon either being selected/clicked on. Not really sure how to at the moment. Any suggestions?

Comment: No druapl way to achieve this. Need to use some javascript.

Comment: I learned that you should tie this to attributes as I listed below, however it is not working as intended. Thanks for the advice@Nikhil

    `$form['Package']['FirstName'] = array(
    '#default_value' => t('First Name'),
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#maxlength'=> 255,
    '#required' => TRUE,
    '#attributes' => array(
    '#onblur' => "if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'First Name'}",
    '#onfocus' => "if (this.value == 'First Name') {this.value = ''}",  
    ),`

Comment: Fixed: The correct code for erasing the default values in a textfield, etc. is:

    $form['Package']['FirstName'] = array(
    '#default_value' => t('First Name'),
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#maxlength'=> 255,
    '#required' => TRUE,
    '#attributes' => array(
    **'onblur' => "if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'First Name'}",
    'onfocus' => "if (this.value == 'First Name') {this.value = ''}",**  
    ),
     
    );

Don't forget to remove the # call as the array attributes are additions not Drupal specific options..

Comment: Yeah #attributes its the better way. Nice finding. Also post answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct code for erasing the default values in a textfield, etc. is:

```
$form['Package']['FirstName'] = array(
  '#default_value' => t('First Name'),
  '#type' => 'textfield',
  '#maxlength'=> 255,
  '#required' => TRUE,
  '#attributes' => array(
    'onblur' => "if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'First Name'}",
    'onfocus' => "if (this.value == 'First Name') {this.value = ''}", 
  ),   
);
```

Comment: But that's not the drupal way!

Answer (score 2):

What do you mean for "default value"? Do you need to save this value or just to use it as a placeholder?

In this case you can obtain the goal without javascript:

```
$form['Package']['FirstName'] = array(
  '#type' => 'textfield',
  '#maxlength'=> 255,
  '#required' => TRUE,
  '#attributes' => array(
    'placeholder' => t('First Name'),
  ),   
);
```

Comment: This is a way better answer since it uses the built in Ajax and just simply works!